# Why am I getting "size mismatch" errors from the Iceland mirror?

Tags: apt

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 (clean install) I fetch a bunch of program via synaptic (installed specially), all programs worked except Gimp 2.8. So I tried purging Gimp, install again (no luck). Checked broken packages and reinstalled them. When using the Software center I get this MSG:

```
Failed to fetch http://is.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openexr/libopenexr6_1.6.1-4.1_amd64.deb Size mismatch
```

Tried also this:

```
sudo apt-get purge gimp*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

And get this MSG:

```
Failed to fetch http://is.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openexr/libopenexr6_1.6.1-4.1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I am wondering if the Icelandic Archive has an outdated version or something?

would really like to install Gimp 2.8 but Gimp 2.6 is OK to.

I am also wondering if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you changed the mirror? and is still giving you that error?

Comment: It worked. just did it this evening. I found there is another mirror or archive in Iceland (didn't try it) the norway one worked. I now have Gimp 2.8. Still feels slower then 2.6 but that is a problem I also have on my windblows 7 computer. Thanks again for your help and follow up :) Were could I go to learn more about the (for exemple) the commands you sent me and maybe general terminal commands?. Thanks again, regards from Iceland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Iceland mirror (Siminn hf) is [one week out of date.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)

Please try one of these up-to-date mirrors that should be close to you, network-wise:

Norway: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ftp.blix.eu-archive
Netherlands: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/nl3.archive.ubuntu.com-archive
UK: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ftp.ticklers.org-archive

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am a bit of a newbie in regards to terminal action and using synaptic so forgive me for asking how to do I activate the norway mirror? Why is the the Icelandic mirror one week out of date? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: No need for the terminal. Please press alt-f2 and type `gksudo software-properties-gtk` and scroll down  by country and manually select the mirror.  Then press update, I think, or type `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal. Unfortunately, nothing you can do about the .is mirror -- not unless you know someone high up in Siminn management ;). A lot of mirrors are like that, it's just your luck that this is the only local one for you.

Comment: YES. it worked. Were can I learn more about the commands you sent me? would like to become more confident in what I am doing in Ubuntu and learn more. But thanks for the help.

Comment: @BirgirFreyr: in that case, please accept the answer (tick/check mark on left), so that the question is marked as closed and future readers know the solution worked. :)   I will add another comment shortly with some resources that may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification: The mirror is provided by Listaháskólinn ( LHI.is ), and yes, it is out of date and has been for a long time now.

The solution is to redirect archive searches to another mirror. I have used se.archive instead, since it's net-wise pretty close (on Nordunet/Sunet).

The solution is to do:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/is.archive/se.archive/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Which switches your source of packages to Sweden.

**Please note:** All traffic destined for NORDUNET should be handled as domestic traffic (isl: ekkert útlandaniðurhal) since the traffic is routed through the RIX which is a domestic end-point for the telcos.