# Why isn't the Iceland mirror working?

Tags: updates, software-center, downloads

I have already tried

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but then it cant connect to [to is.archive.ubuntu.com][1]

and when i try to use update manager this comes

```
W:Failed to fetch http://is.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg
Unable to connect to is.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
....
```

Comment: First check your internet connection and Change your **Mirror** from software sources , and try installing vlc through CLI as `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Comment: It seems down for everyone as here http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/is.archive.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Iceland mirror has [often been out of date](https://askubuntu.com/a/165294/58612) and is now offline. Blame the maintainer/operator Siminn hf.

Unfortunately that is the only Ubuntu mirror in Iceland. Please try one of these up-to-date mirrors that should be close to you, network-wise:

- Norway: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ftp.blix.eu-archive
- Netherlands: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/nl3.archive.ubuntu.com-archive
- UK: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ftp.ticklers.org-archive

You can change them from *Software Sources* in the Software Center, or press `Alt+F2` and run `gksudo software-properties-gtk`, and see the below answer:

> [How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror)

Answer (score 3):

This needs to be corrected. Síminn did not run the official Icelandic Ubuntu mirror. That was being run by LHÍ (Icelandic Academy of the Arts). They had trouble with it for a while.

Yesterday, a change to the DNS record for is.archive.ubuntu.com was made so now instead of pointing toward the LHÍ mirror it points to speglar.simnet.is which is in fact run by Síminn and has always been rock solid. So hopefully now the mirror will behave.

Answer (score 0):

there is also http://ftp.rhnet.is/ubuntu/ and http://ubuntu.lhi.is/ubuntu/

Comment: Er you need to teach him how to actually set the mirror...